# Using Angularjs/Nodejs/Passportjs in order make api calls

Tags: angularjs, node.js, passport.js

I wanna build a system where a user can access different apis like youtube/facebook/twitter and display all the data he wants on one single page.

For authentication I found passportjs and after reading [this](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-linking-all-accounts-together) tutorial I understand most of it.

Now I want to make the api-call in AngularJS but I have no idea how this is possible.
I know how to use service/factory in AngularJS in order to make a http-request.
For me [this](http://blog.jpamorgan.com/searching-the-itunes-api-asynchronously-with-angular-js/) tutorial was really helpful. At the end I have no idea how it is possible to use Passportjs and Angularjs together in order achieve my goal.

Can someone help me with this problem or give me tips how this is possible?

Comment: Look on github. There's this https://github.com/DaftMonk/angular-passport, and others